# Text classification for russian language

Tags: python, text, scikit-learn

I faced a problem with text classification where I need to classify russian texts. For feature extraction, I use scikit learn TfidfTransformer and CountVectorizer, but after compiling the code there is a mistake:

```
'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: 
invalid continuation byte'.
```

How can I correct this mistake? Here is the code in Python:

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA

import os
import nltk
import re
import sys
from nltk import NaiveBayesClassifier
import nltk.classify
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re



data_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('/home/lena/','corpus'))

official_path = os.path.join(data_path,'official')
#print official_path
official2_path = os.path.join(data_path,'official_2')

talk_path = os.path.join(data_path,'talk')

talk2_path = os.path.join(data_path,'talk_2')

#fiction_path = os.path.join(data_path,'fiction')

#fiction2_path = os.path.join(data_path,'fiction_2')

def get_text(path):

    with open(path,'rU') as file:

        line = file.readlines()

        return ''.join(line)

def get_textdir(path):

    filelist = os.listdir(path)

    all_text = [get_text(os.path.join(path,f)) for f in filelist]

    return all_text

all_talk = get_textdir(talk_path)
all_official = get_textdir(official_path)

official_2 = get_textdir(official2_path)
talk_2 = get_textdir(talk2_path)

train_set = all_talk 
test_set = talk_2 
stopWords = stopwords.words('russian')

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stopWords)
print vectorizer

train = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set).toarray()
test = vectorizer.transform(test_set).toarray()
print 'train set', train
print 'test set', test

transformer.fit(train)

print transformer.transform(train).toarray()

transformer.fit(test)

tfidf = transformer.transform(test)
print tfidf.todense()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `charset` (or in 0.14, `encoding`) parameter on the vectorizer. For Russian text, that would probably be

```
CountVectorizer(charset='koi8r', stop_words=stopWords)
```

(but don't take my word for it and run something like `chardet` or `file` on your text files).